# Python returns IndexError: string index out of range on this funtion why

Tags: python

I don't understand why this code doesn't work:

```
def reverse(string):
    rev_string = []
    for c in range(len(string)):
        rev_string[c]=string[(len(string))-c]
    str(rev_string)
    return rev_string
print(reverse("google"))
```

and throws this error message:

> IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: you know there is a `reversed` builtin-function?

Comment: You can also do `return string[::-1]` to reverse a string, if you are just trying to reverse a string without a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems in your code.

1. rev_string is an empty list you can not index it, you can use `append` instead;
2. you need to use `''.join` instead of `str` to make a string from a list;
3. list index is 0 based, so max index is `len(string) - 1`:

---

```
def reverse(string):

    rev_string = []
    for c in range(len(string)):
        rev_string.append(string[len(string)-c-1])
​
    return ''.join(rev_string)

print(reverse("google"))
# elgoog
```

Answer (score 0):

when len=6 and c=0.
you'll get indexerror, since there is no index6

Comment: knowing that the logic behind this code itself won't work